# Ionic on Ios content page auto slide down

Tags: html, ios, angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I've a problem whit my app in ios.
I don't know why the content of any page or modal auto slide down.
With android everything works fine.

[Link to video](https://im5.ezgif.com/tmp/ezgif-5-57f17cb418.gif)

Anyone kwon at least where I can see why i've this problem?
I really searched everywhere and I was not able to find neither the cause nor the solution.

this is the output of ionic info:

```
cli packages: (/usr/local/lib/node_modules)

    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.13.0
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.13.0

global packages:

    cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.0.1

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts : 3.0.0
    Cordova Platforms  : android 6.2.3 ios 4.4.0
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.7.1

System:

    Node  : v6.11.1
    npm   : 5.4.2
    OS    : macOS High Sierra
    Xcode : Xcode 9.0 Build version 9A235

Misc:

    backend : legacy
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to upgrade your project to [**Ionic 3.7.1**](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/releases). It has lot of features for [**iphoneX support**](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/commit/112d4f5).

**This is the list**

- feat(cordova): add ios11 safeAreaInsets support
- feat(cordova): ios11 padding mixin
- fix(sass): add a mixin for the safe-area-padding
- style(sass): fix sass lint errors
- style(): tabs, footer, content changes
- fix(): lint
- style(sass): fix sass linter error
- refactor(footer): use safe area for all modes
- fix(tabs): increase font-weight of tabs for iOS 11
- style(): fix content padding and sizing
- style(sass): fix linter and remove unused vars
- style(): actionsheet, toast, header updates
- fix(): sass lint

Comment: Can you show the `Ionic info`? Put under your question above.

Comment: Try this `ionic cordova platform remove ios` after that `ionic cordova platform add ios`

Comment: I get this error when I types `ionic cordova platform add ios`:
`✖ Uploading source images to prepare for transformations - failed!

HTTP Error 400: POST https://res.ionic.io/api/v1/upload

{"Error":"unable to read uploaded image","Width":0,"Height":0,"Type":"png","Vector":false}`

Comment: and then I still have the issue on the device